# ksh print command displays additional characters

Tags: shell, printing, scripting, ksh

I have a variable named DB_DIALECT which should contain a string "org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect". The string is exported from a CSV file.

When I'm trying to print DB_DIALECT contents like

```
print -r ${DB_DIALECT}
```

I get the following output (last 3 letters are repeated)

```
org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect  
etc
```

Through trail and error I found that something like this fixes the problem

```
print -r ${DB_DIALECT} | sed 's/[[:digit:]]//g'
```

Since I'm new to shell scripting this doesn't make much sense to me. Can anyone explain why are those last characters repeated, please?

One more thing I can't figure out is the output of

```
print -r ${DB_DIALECT} | od -c
```

which is

```
0000000   o   r   g   .   h   i   b   e   r   n   a   t   e   .   d  i
0000020   a   l   e   c   t   .   S   Q   L   S   e   r   v   e   r  D
0000040   i   a   l   e   c   t  \n 
0000047   
t  \n 
0000053
```

Answer (score 1):

'od -c' (character) is showing you've got some *extra* characters on the end of the expected string; unfortunately it's hard to tell exactly what some of those characters are. ("Duh, Mark!" ?).

The output from 'od -d' (decimal) or 'od -x' (hex) may be of more use since they should display the decimal/hex values of the *extra* characters.

---

In the mean time, the bigger question is: How'd those *extra* characters get into the variable?

And the answer is: You need to provide a bit more detail on the contents and format of that CSV file, where/how the CSV file originated from (may help in determining the format), plus the command(s) you used to populate the DB_DIALECT variable.